# Check if a date is in the future

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I check from within a Django template whether a given date is in the future?

Something like:

```
{% if event.date > now %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a function on event named `in_future`, that will compare `event.date` with `datetime.now()` and use it in the template. Don't put unnecessary logic into template.

Or as Manoj suggested, you can have a custom filter `in_the_future` and call it:

```
{% if event.date|in_the_future %}
```

It's as simple as:

```
@register.filter
def in_the_future(value):
    return value > datetime.now()
```

Comment: +1. Register this function as a custom filter and you'll be all set.